# `gomobile build` and `gomobile install` throws "gomobile: EOF"

Tags: android, go, gomobile

I'm trying to build an android application using gomobile but the commands `gomobile install` and `gomobile build` fail with `gomobile: EOF` . Before this error I was getting this error:

`# golang.org/x/mobile/gl
In file included from /root/go/src/golang.org/x/mobile/gl/gl.go:17:0:
work.h:6:23: fatal error: GLES2/gl2.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.` but it was fixed with `yum install make gcc mesa-libGLES-devel mesa-libEGL-devel`.

The application is mostly a networking application. Here are the imports. Do only certain packages work with gomobile or all of them?

```
"golang.org/x/mobile/app"
"golang.org/x/net/websocket"
"os/exec"
"flag"
"fmt"
log "github.com/golang/glog"
"io/ioutil"
"net"
"net/http"
"net/url"
"strconv"
```

OS: Fedora 22.

More info: I'm able to build https://github.com/golang/mobile/blob/master/example/network/main.go so I can only assume the issue is specific to my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It failed because AndroidManifest.xml was empty.